# PHP send email depending on the selected value from combobox

Tags: php, email, button, combobox

I'd like to send 2 different emails to notify applicants of their application for scholarship. If the user selects Approve from the combobox, then the system will automatically send an email notification to the email address of the applicant, otherwise, will send a revoke notification. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
<strong>Applicant ID:</strong> <?php echo $id; ?><br />
<strong>Applicant name: </strong> 
<input type="text" name="username" readonly value="<?php echo $lastname. "," . $firstname. " " .substr($middlename, 0,1); ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Username: </strong><input type="text" readonly name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /> <br />
<strong>Password: </strong><input type="text" readonly name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" /> <br />

<strong>Manage Application: </strong><select name="status">
<?php
    $selection = array(
    0 => "Pending",
    1 => "Approve",
    2 => "Revoke" );

    foreach($selection as $key => $value)
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $key . '"';
        if ($status == $key)
        echo ' selected="selected"';
        echo '>' . $value . '</option>';
        echo ' <br />';
    }
?>
</select>
<br />

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><img src="../../images/login.png"   />Update</button>


<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if($selection == 1){

$to = '.$email.';
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test email'; 
//define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
$message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail."; 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
//send the email
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
echo("<p>Congrats!</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
}
else if($selection == 2)
{
$to = $email;
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test email'; 
//define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
$message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail."; 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
//send the email
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
echo("<p>Sorry your application is revoked!</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
}


} // end of if button pressed

?>

 <a href="../index.php"><button type="button"><img src="../../images/back.png"/>Back</button></a>
</div>
</form>
```

But when I check on the email it didn't send. And Is this right?

```
  $to = $email;
```

I got the $email from a row['EmailAddress'];

Please help me figure out what I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: what is this ? '.$email.'; after if selection == 1

Comment: I got the $email from a row['EmailAddress'];

Comment: @SaifuddinSarker if i remove selected="selected", it won't print in my combobox

Comment: but you have not define row['EmailAddress'] anywhere in your code. first do die($to). then check what it getting in $to variable

Comment: I have defined it somewhere in my code $email = row['EmailAddress']; I happened to not include it on the one that I posted here.

Comment: @ripa there's no value getting into $to variable. but when i put an email address to it: $to = 'myemail@email.com'; it's sending.

Comment: so you need assign email in $to. assign email. It'll work fine.

Comment: @ripa but i need to assign the proper email of an applicant. If I only put one email address to it, other applicants won't be notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting posted value. so get like this `$to=$_POST["your email address field name"]` . hope it will work fine. try it.

try below ode

```
<?php
$selection = array(
0 => "Pending",
1 => "Approve",
2 => "Revoke" );
```

$option="";

```
foreach($selection as $key => $value)
{
    if ($status == $key)
        $sel='selected="selected"';

    $option.='<option value="'. $key.'" '.$sel.'>'. $value . '</option>';


    echo $option.' <br />';
}
```

?>

Comment: Hi I tried your code, it's working but the logic in the if else if statement of mine is a bit confusing. I selected the approve, but it's getting into my revoke statement.

Comment: don't understand. what's happening?